# does a question get deleted after a bug is fixed?

Tags: discussion, questions

I reported a bug a while ago and the bug was fixed. Good job.

But i can't seem to find my original question.

any ideas?

ps. my question was not closed or voted down as far as i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be, if we consider the bug highly temporal, build related, and quickly fixed -- and of no value for any future searchers who might encounter it.

Comment: what if that bug comes again?

Comment: " **if** we consider"

Comment: I understand this is not a serious answer. A question which leads to a bug being fixed has earned it's storage space.

Comment: @abel Actually, this is a serious answer. See [this similar inquiry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51281/is-it-necessary-to-delete-time-local-closed-bug-reports-on-meta) I made months ago. Sometimes, things *aren't* the same bug, and it causes confusion (and in some cases, incorrect duplicate closings).