# Questions / bug-reports get deleted on meta without notice

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Questions and bug-reports seem to get deleted without notice here on meta.

I posted a bug report about 20 minutes ago, which just disappeared. This question

- [So we can't report bugs anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105890/so-we-cant-report-bugs-anymore)

was posted as a follow up (which politely asked why), and was also deleted without notice.

**My question:**

Is this behavior documented / motivated somewhere?

(I'm fine with it if there is some official motivation saying that "noise is removed" to keep the sites clean, provided there is an objective understandable definition of noise.)

---

(PS. [My original question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105882/what-happened-to-the-author-info-avatar/105898#105898) was restored and answered. -- Thanks Jeff, I appreciate it. :)

(PPS. But is now removed again. I guess because it sort of clutters the forum.)

Comment: No it's not documented, and it's non-deterministic.  I'm not sure why they wouldn't have left at least the first bug report in place.

Comment: Since Tim prevents us from voting on Jeff's answer, I need to state my disagreement here, rather than by downvoting the answer.

Comment: [Somewhat related post on localized-closed bug reports and their deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51281/is-it-necessary-to-delete-time-local-closed-bug-reports-on-meta).

Answer (score -3):

If the bug is related to a build artifact that will exist for all of 5 minutes, after which point it will automatically correct itself -- this "bug" is of no future value and does not need to exist at all.

Basically, "wait 5 minutes, and you'll never see this again for the entire history of recorded time."

Sort of like "too localized", but of even less value...

edit: Fine, though I think it's pointless to dwell on a 15 minute issue, here's the master: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105882/what-happened-to-the-author-info-avatar

Comment: Why didn't you leave one report with an answer/comment stating this for the duration and *then* delete that.

Comment: Aha, I can understand that. But can't you close the question with some close-message or something? It's extremely frustrating to see pages you're reading / discussing on just vanish.

Comment: In this particular case it's worth noting that there were at least (by my count without access to deleted questions) 3 bug reports for this, probably more. Wouldn't it be easier just to respond to the first bug report, say "this is a problem with the latest build and will be fixed in 5 minutes", fix the problem, and then deal with any duplicate bug reports after the problem is fixed, instead of wasting time deleting every repeat bug report (because multiple users think, "odd, there's no bug reports for this yet!") and confusing the users?

Comment: @nhinkle I like rewriting history, actually, and this build situation should never have existed. Now it doesn't. Also you're talking about a fifteen minute interval here..

Comment: Ah yes. We've always been at war with Eastasia, and the builds have always been flawless. Understood :D

Comment: @Jeff: What you are doing extremely irritates users. Your last comment just shows how much you respect your users. You don't like that there was a bug in your software so you delete every occurrence of a bug report? Seriously? As others have mentioned, just answer one and link all others to that one. After the bug is fixed and some time has passed, you can still delete those bug reports, because THEN they are of no more value.

Comment: @dan feel free to refer to this one, the one you're commenting on right now.

Comment: @Jeff: I don't understand your comment. "Refer to this one"? What do you mean?

Comment: I totally agree that it's completely okay to delete bug reports, but why not leave one alive, put a "It has been fixed now, thanks" answer underneath, wait 12 hours, delete with no one ever noticing. Just to prevent this kind of discussion every time

Comment: @Daniel, you'll see.

Comment: _"and you'll never see this again for the entire history of recorded time"_ -- but let us, the small ones, keep a little reminder that even the Great Ones make a mistake sometimes. ;-)

Comment: Idea for a new field on a bug tracker: Should this bug ever have existed: Yes / No

Comment: @Jeff: Although you undeleted the question, your comment shows, that you don't seem to understand the real issue here. When you delete those bug reports without any feedback, the users can't know whether it is a bug that will be fixed in no time or a new feature you would like to suppress discussion about. Clarifying that it is just a bug and will be fixed will prevent all this uproar and will cost you less time than all the deleting and discussion afterwards... Don't you think so, too?

Comment: @dan is it even *credible* to posit that no author information on any answers could possibly be "a new feature that we would like to suppress discussion about"? And the YSOD is our new homepage design...

Comment: Cool! I like the new policy. Time rewrite 90% complete. Tomorrow, this is how we will remember the past 60 minutes:  http://bit.ly/oPA4xG

Comment: @Jeff: Well, yes. Features were introduced in the past that created a big uproar in the community - the removal of the envelope for example. Questions, answers and comments where massively deleted back then. A lot of people thought the new implementation didn't make sense and saw the removal of the envelope as a bug. So, just because I think a change doesn't make sense, doesn't mean it is a bug - it could be a new feature. After the questions about this particular bug got deleted, I actually began fearing that this was a new feature, because I could think about some arguments supporting it.

Comment: @Daniel come on, it was a five minute bug. I'm in favour of putting this to rest now. The first bug report has been undeleted. What more could one want?

Comment: @Pekka: I think it is important that Jeff understands our side of this discussion. It has nothing to do with that particular question but with the general behavior of the mod team on meta. Basically, I hate coming here because of the way people are treated. I would like this to change.

Comment: @Daniel, *I think it is important that Jeff understands our side of this discussion* -- He does.

Comment: @aioobe: How do you know? It doesn't look like this to me. Or he does and doesn't care - which would be even worse.

Comment: Folks, this horse has been beaten to death. The fact that Jeff decided to restore the first report and slap a [featured] tag on it shows that he does, in fact understand the arguments here. The requested action was taken, the bug is fixed, I don't see the need for any additional discussion. </thread>