# Please do not delete questions, even if they become obsolete

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions / bug-reports get deleted on meta without notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105894/questions-bug-reports-get-deleted-on-meta-without-notice)

Today a bug on SO made all answerers appear as anonymous. There were a bunch of questions about it quickly springing up here on Meta. Some got closed as dupes (fine), but [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105891/answers-appear-as-anonymous) stayed open for a while. While we were still contemplating what happened in chat, I checked other sites and found they don't have the problem. So I wanted to added that info, in case it would help to nail the bug, but oops, the question was gone. Then I checked, and the problem was gone also.

As I have said here before, attempting to change history that way is stupid. Please don't do it. *What's wrong with adding and answer saying "Yes, we failed in this small detail for 4mins. It's fixed now. Sorry, we're only humans." and let the party go on?*

We're all programmers here, and we all know how such things happen. You have three quarters of a million of users, no doubt thousands see a problem even if it only appears for a few minutes. Why leave them in the dark? What harm would it do to SO to admit a small problem? People put time into investigating what seems to be a bug, so why are deleting their efforts without even bothering to acknowledging that there actually *was* a problem?

***Please stop trying to attempt to change history.*** It doesn't work.
The problem will be visible (in the chat, for example) for as long as this site's records are preserved, only that it now references dead meat. That stinks.

---

***Note:*** *This is the second time I've posted this question. The first time it was closed and deleted by Jeff very quickly. However, [I was made to believe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105899/where-did-my-rep-go/105901#105901) that it was closed due to me accidentally using a phrase that, while used in speech a lot, must not be written. So I edited the phrase out and posted the question again.

If this second version is still not acceptable to some rules I failed to know or remember, I kindly ask to be made aware of the problem, so that I have a chance to fix it, rather than the question being deleted without even giving me a chance to see what I did wrong.*

Comment: @Michael: The OP clearly states, why he asks the Question again.

Comment: Are you referring to this bug? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105882/what-happened-to-the-author-info-avatar

Comment: @Als: what do you mean?

Comment: @Michael: Refer to OP's *Note:* It says explicitly the reason.

Comment: @Als: still not seeing it... This topic is discussed in the question I marked as a dupe.

Comment: This isn't a dupe because it's about the general problem, while the other is on a specific problem (reference in this question also).

Comment: *What's wrong with adding and answer saying "Yes, we failed in this small detail for 4mins. It's fixed now. Sorry, we're only humans." and let the party go on?* -- Uhm, have you looked around here on Meta? There's a gazillion posts here with exactly that content. Don't be ridiculous.

Comment: It's really not, @Lance. It's *inspired* by the specific issue, but it contains a general discussion. *"Questions / bug-reports get deleted on meta without notice... Is this behavior documented / motivated somewhere?"*

Comment: @balpha: Yes, I have looked around here. (Where do you think my disgust comes from? `:)`) I'm not sure how your point argues _against_ my question, however. So since it has been done before, doesn't that raise the question even more urgently why it hadn't been done this time?

Comment: "The first time it was deleted"...oh the irony

Comment: @eternal: Exactly [my thoughts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105899/where-did-my-rep-go/105901#comment-271734).